# Firebase deploy: Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy my first function with firebase cloud functions.
I deployed the standard function "helloWorld" without problem, but then, when I added this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
```

firebase deploy didn't work anymore and caused this error:

> Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL, config is actually{"projectId":"PROJECT-ID","storageBucket":"PROJECT-ID.appspot.com","locationId":"europe-west"}
>
> If you are unit testing, please set process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG

How can I set config or the value of databaseURL? I don't find anywhere the file where these things are written... I also looked in documentation but I didn't find anything useful
I tried also with

```
admin.initializeApp(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
```

but this give me this error:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> Error: Invalid Firebase app options passed as the first argument to initializeApp() for the app named "[DEFAULT]". Options must be a non-null object.

Comment: You have to add package.json file and include the firebase-admin package there. You are using node?

Comment: I believe we cant use the firebase functions with the free plan :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you're being affected by a change that was made a few months ago where the `databaseURL` is no longer auto-created when you create a new project.

If that is the case, you you can force the `databaseURL` to be generated by going to the [Realtime Database panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database) in the Firebase console. If this indeed fixes the problem, it might be worth [filing a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the Firebase support team.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have a default database created. Visit your [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and create at least one real-time database.

You can explicit select a database instance with `functions.database.instance()` View [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_#instance)

Comment: This works solution is the only one which worked for my issue – HOWEVER I had to add  database name to the instance method, like so: `functions.database.instance('<databaseName>')`