# firebase cloud function error when trying to record a record change by using timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

goal: provide time stamps when a record in 'job application' was updated.

I got an error when I added the following lines to my cloud function::

```
exports.touch = functions.database.ref('/job application/').onWrite(
    (change, context) => admin.database().ref('/lastmodified').set(context.timestamp));
```

Here is the error:

```
Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL, config is actually{"projectId":"XXXX","storageBucket":"XXXXX","locationId":"us-east4"}
 If you are unit testing, please set process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG
```

I am trying to add time stamps to the collection 'job application'.

I am trying to follow the following snip:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/lastmodified-tracking/functions/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, you have to specify `databaseURL` in your firebase configuration. URL’s are of form `projectID.firebaseio.com`.

Here is the configuration example:

```
{
  "projectId":"xxxxx",
  "storageBucket":"xxxxx",
  "locationId":"us-east4",
  "databaseURL":"https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
}
```

Also check this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66211385/18265570)